# Sorting 3-Bytes Unsigned Numbers Efficiently

Tags: sorting, assembly, x86-16

In 8086, how can I sort 3-bytes unsigned numbers efficiently?

**My current solution:**

- Compare upper 16-bits
- if they are equal, compare lower 8-bits
- Swap according to the result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use a compare based algorithm. Use a counting based one. For 24 bit integers you can sort your numbers in three passes of bucket sort with 8 bits each.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bucket_sort

Pick a bucket size of 8 bits. That is a natural choice for your CPU architecture.

Bucket sort algorithms usually beat comparison based sort algorithms if the number of elements is quite high and if the array is not already partially sorted.

Comment: A bucket sort might not be the best choice for small inputs due to its out-of-place nature and rather large setup (initializing 256 buckets).

Answer (score 0):

I would expect 24 bit numbers to be stored in doubleword locations. My advice would be to compare the top 8 bits and if they are equal compare the bottom 16 bits.
Asking about efficiency is rather useless if you don't provide more information and code sample.